# what is difference between API and Implementation in programming?

Tags: api, implementation

In programming world, some says API is defining a specification (what) and implementation is actual implementation of (how). In an example of manufacturing a car, API represents specifying what car needs to have such as a wheel, brake, accelerator and etc. And implementation is like a car manufacturer actually implement mentioned components. Did I understand the concept right?

Answer (score 0):

APIs often come in the form of a library that includes specifications for routines, data structures, object classes, and variables. The API describes and prescribes the expected behavior while the library is an actual implementation of this set of rules.

A single API can have multiple implementations (or none, being abstract) in the form of different libraries that share the same programming interface.